# Make Tuples from Specific Pandas Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, e.g.

```
   one  two  three  four  five
0    1    2      3     4     5
1    1    1      1     1     1
```

What I would like is to be able to convert only a select number of columns to a list, such that we obtain:

```
[[1,2],[1,1]]
```

This is the rows 0,1, where we are selecting columns one and two.

Similarly if we selected columns one, two, four:

```
[[1,2,4],[1,1,1]]
```

Ideally I would like to avoid iteration of rows as it is slow!

Comment: Do you want a list of tuples or a list of lists?

Comment: right now i need tuples, but in the future I will probably be needing lists of lists so that would be great

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select just those columns with:

```
In [11]: df[['one', 'two']]
Out[11]:
   one  two
0    1    2
1    1    1
```

and get the list of lists from the underlying numpy array using tolist:

```
In [12]: df[['one', 'two']].values.tolist()
Out[12]: [[1, 2], [1, 1]]

In [13]: df[['one', 'two', 'four']].values.tolist()
Out[13]: [[1, 2, 4], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Note: this should never really be necessary unless this is your end game... it's going to be much more efficient to do the *work* inside pandas or numpy.

Comment: tahnks @andy I wonder which method is better, my own below or yours. Seem pretty much of a muchness

Comment: @redrubia the values attribute is the numpy underlying numpy array, tolist *converts* to the list of lists you were hoping for. It really depends on what the next step is! Otherwise this is the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)!

Answer (score 2):

So I worked out how to do it.

Firstly we select the columns we would like the values from:

```
 y = x[['one','two']]
```

This gives us a subset df.

Now we can choose the values:

```
> y.values

array([[1, 2],
       [1, 1]])
```